# How can I run MUnit tests outside of Workbench under Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, testing-and-verification

I would like to run MUnit tests from the command line.  On Mac OS, I can do this:

```
AppendTo[$Path, "/Applications/Wolfram Workbench.app/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/13/1/.cp/MathematicaSourceVersioned/Head"];

<< MUnit`
```

and then use the MUnit functions such as TestRun to run the tests.  However, on Linux, the MUnit package is stored within a jar file (com.wolfram.eclipse.testing_2.0.126.jar), rather than being "bare" in the filesystem.  Workbench must be able to load the package; is it possible to load MUnit from the jar file?  One solution would be to extract MUnit into a temporary directory each time you wanted to load it, but this is quite ugly.

Comment: I would suggest to extract it.  It for development, not for end users, so just extract it once and put it at some fixed location.  (That's what I did.)