# How to Develop Paclets in Workbench Considering the Recent Changes in PacletInfo.wl Format and Supporting Functions?

Tags: packages, workbench, paclets

**WRI Technical Support [CASE:4868964]**

---

#### Preamble

So far I am using Wolfram Workbench (i.e., a plugin to the Eclipse IDE) to develop packages collecting often used Wolfram Language functionality. For some time now, the way to go about developing, testing, and deploying packages has been the `Paclet system`:

> *Paclets are units of Wolfram functionality, packaged up in a way that allows them to be discovered, installed, updated, and integrated seamlessly into the Wolfram environment. The essential element that makes a paclet is the PacletInfo.wl file, a small, simple file of metadata that describes the paclet, its requirements, and the ways in which it extends the Wolfram environment.*

Unfortunately, starting in `Version 12.1` the format of `PacletInfo.wl` has changed, `` PacletManager` ``  functions have been added to the `` System` ``  context and `Paclet[...]` has become `PacletObject[ ...]`. For more details and advice I would like to point to the new [**tech note**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Paclets.html) in `Version 13`'s documentation center.

While the new format will not be compatible with earlier versions of the Wolfram Langauge, the ease of working with paclets makes "going with the flow of development" an appealing option. Alas, [Wolfram Workbench and its support for Paclet Development](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/961186) appear rather outdated (e.g., `PacletInfo.wl` is not recognized as such, the file structure within the package will not match the new default one etc.).

#### How to Best Use Workbench With the New `PacletInfo.wl` format?

##### Let's start by first *creating a paclet from within a notebook*

```
Needs["PacletTools`];

$pacletDir = FileNameJoin @ { "D:", "git-local" } (* or wherever you develop... *);

(* if $pacletDir does not yet exist, it needs to be created first *)

obj = PacletObject[ <|
    "Name"           -> "MyFirstPaclet",
    "Version"        -> "0.1",
    "WolframVersion" -> "12.2+", (* paclet will be invisible to earlier versions *)
    "Creator"        -> "My Name <me@domain>",
    "Description"    -> "My first package further developed in Workbench.",
    "Extensions"     -> {
        { "Kernel", "Root" -> "Kernel", "Context" -> { "MyFirstPaclet`" } },
        { "Documentation" }
        (* maybe also { "Path" }? Note, that { "FrontEnd" } does not work in 12.3 *)  
    }
|> ];

CreatePaclet[ obj, $pacletDir ] (* creates files and directory structure *)
```

In `$pacletDir` we will now find the following files and directories:

```
MyFirstPaclet/
    Documentation/
    Kernel/
        MyFirstPaclet.wl
    PacletInfo.wl
```

> **QUESTION 1:** Upon inspection we note that `"Creator"` and `"Description"` information has been dropped and is not contained in `PacletInfo.wl`. How can this be avoided and are there appropriate ways to come up with a `PacletInfo.wl` file from within Workbench?

##### We can now *add a project notebook*

We can open a new notebook and save it as `ProjectNotebook.nb` to `$pacletDir/MyFirstPaclet/` (i.e., next to where `PacletInfo.wl` is located). The notebook will be used to test and show the functions contained in the package.

If we were to run a project notebook from outside Workbench, we can do so by adding the following:

```
PacletDirectoryLoad @ NotebookDirectory[];
PacletDataRebuild[]; (* to make sure that changes in PacletInfo.wl are recognized *)

(* the code above is made an `Initialization Cell`*)

Needs[ "MyFirstPaclet`" ]

SayHello[ "Bob" ] (* this is by default included in MyFirstPaclet.wl :) *)
(* Hello Bob! *)
```

When we run a project notebook directly from Workbench, as far as I can see, neither `PacletDirectoryLoad[ ]`, `PacletDataRebuild[ ]` nor `Needs[ ]` are needed: Simply select `ProjectNotebook.nb` in the `Package Explorer` and then right click: `Run as > 1 Wolfram`). So, when we add another function:

```
BeginPackage["MyFirstPaclet`"]

...

SayGoodbye

Begin["`Private`"] 

...

SayGoodbye[ ___ ] := Print[ "Goodbye." ]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

... and save these changes in the editor, we can immediately use the function in the running `ProjectNotebook.nb` as is the usual development process in Workbench.

> **Question 2:** How can a project notebook be employed that is automatically created by Workbench, e.g., when you select the main directory and run the project as is usually the case in Workbench?

> **Question 3:** How to best deploy a paclet from Workbench?

Comment: For further reference one must of course point at Szabolcs excellent posts [132064](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132064/764) and the linked posts as well. In comparison we see the changes that the `Paclet system` has undergone.

Comment: Good question! I'm waiting until 13. comes out for the Paclet Repo before I dig in but I think the big thing will be that you don't _need_ Workbench for paclet dev.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I am aware of the priority given to Notebook development. But my personal preference (_want_) still remains: Code development -> Workbench, Documentation development -> Notebook.

Comment: You can still write the code in Workbench or IntelliJ or whatever your preferred IDE is (and I would recommend that you do). It looks like all of the config settings are going to be migrated to the NB interface though.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I am not yet convinced about Notebooks being the thing for version control (e.g., GitHub)?

Comment: Agreed, the actual raw NB is definitely not great for VCS (but the autogenerate packages can be fine if set up well/if you do a bunch of leg-work beforehand) but I think that's getting off topic. I'll come back to this once 13. is out, if I still have access to Mathematica

Comment: @b3m2a1 Imagine merging two git branches together when working with notebooks ... This is the situation I'm in now (documentation only), and it's a major pain to sort out the differences ... For as long as everything is linear, incremental changes to a file, there's no problem. But as soon as you get divergent branches, notebooks become a major inconvenience.

Comment: Or maybe I just don't know how to deal with them properly.

Comment: @Szabolcs fair point. Docs still need VCS. Was there ever a way to do plain-text docs that would get auto-converted to NB? I can't imagine WRI would do something like that but I can definitely see the use case. Maybe something like MD -> NB and then put it in docs style or something

Comment: Just adding a cross-reference to another way to [build paclets and documentation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262964/18437).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### A New Kind of Tutorial

Since some time has passed now without getting any answers, I have experimented myself using

```
$Version
(* 12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2021) *)
```

and

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

Plugin: Wolfram Workbench Core (10.1.1087)
```

So bear with me.

### 1 Creating Paclets in Wolfram Workbench 3.0 as of v12.2+

##### 1.1 Create a new project

By selecting `File>New>Project` we can enter the process of creating a new project as usual:

[image]

###### 1.1.1 Select a wizard

We may select the `Application Project` wizard that is well suited for Wolfram Language package development:

[image]

###### 1.1.2 Wolfram Language project name and location

Next we create a new project called `MyFirstPaclet`. We can use the default workspace or a location of our choice. Since I am also using git for version control, I am collecting my projects in a directory called `\git-local`. Using the `Browse...` button I can create a new subdirectory `\git-local\MyFirstPaclet` and select it as Location:

[image]

###### 1.1.3 Project References

In the next dialog we are asked for referenced projects—I will skip this for our minimal example by choosing `Next >`.

###### 1.1.4 Application details

Finally, we need to give the application name which I also set to `MyFirstPaclet`. I will leave the default choices for the boxes unchanged. Note, that we are *not choosing to create* `PactletInfo.m` here—we will take care of this manually later on.

[image]

Upon selecting `Finish` we should have a project structure that looks like this in the `Package Explorer` window (note, that I deselected any filters to show all files):

[image]

##### 1.2 Adapt the project structure

###### 1.2.1 Modify the project's properties

By right clicking on the project directory in the `Package Explorer` we can modify the project's properties. The `Wolfram` entry has `` <<MyFirstPaclet` ``  listed in the window titled `Execution Build Command`—we get rid of this and close the dialog with `Ok`.

[image]
[image]

###### 1.2.2 Move and delete files

We will not need `init.m` and can thus *delete* it. We then *move* the file `MyFirstPaclet.m` into the directory `\Kernel` and we then *rename* (Refactor>Rename in the context menu) it to `MyFirstPaclet.wl` to be on the modern side of things; also we do not need the additional directory `MyFirstPaclet` so we can *move* the `\Kernel` directory to the top level and *delete* the subdirectory `\MyFirstPaclet`. We also *delete* the hidden file `.WolframResources` (it will always be recreated upon changes to the project properties).

Our project structure should by now look like this:

[image]

##### 1.3 Create `PacketInfo.wl`

###### 1.3.1 Create custom `PacletInfo` file

Select the top level project directory `MyFirstPaclet` and enter the context menu with a right click to create a new `Other...` file and select the wizard for `PacletInfo File`:

[image][image]

In the `PacletInfo file` wizard dialog we change `PacletInfo.m` to `PacletInfo.wl` and enter the paclet name acordingly. We can also deselect the `Function Paclet` option since we will be completely rewriting the file:

[image]

Upon closing the dialog with `Finish` a `PacletInfo.wl` file has be added at the top level of our project directory.

###### 1.3.2 Modify `PacletInfo.wl`

If it is not yet shown in the editor, we can double click the newly created `PacletInfo.wl` file to enter the editor:

```
(* Paclet Info File *)

(* created 2021.11.02*)

Paclet[
  Name -> "MyFirstPaclet",
  Version -> "0.0.1",
  WolframVersion -> "6+",
  Extensions -> {
    {"Documentation", Language -> "English"}
}]
```

As we can see, the format is old and thus we can simply rewrite the `Paclet[ ]` section to be a `PacletObject[ ]`:

```
(* Paclet Info File *)

(* created 2021.11.02*)

PacletObject[
    <| 
        "Name" -> "MyFirstPaclet",
        "Version" -> "0.1",
        "WolframVersion" -> "12.2+", (* paclet will be invisible to earlier versions *)
        "Creator" -> "Bingo S. Little <bsl@domain>",
        "Description" -> "My first paclet developed in Workbench.",
        "Extensions" -> {
           { "Kernel", "Root" -> "Kernel", "Context"-> { "MyFirstPaclet`" } }
        }
    |>
]
```

### 2 Developing the paclet

##### 2.1 Writing code

We are now al set and can develop our package. In this simple example we will just edit the main package `MyFirstPaclet.wl` in the `/Kernel` directory (to meet the example created in the OP by using `CreatePaclet[ ]`) as follows:

```
(* Wolfram Language Package *)

(* Created by the Wolfram Workbench 02.11.2021 *)

BeginPackage["MyFirstPaclet`"]
(* Exported symbols added here with SymbolName::usage *) 

SayHello

Begin["`Private`"]
(* Implementation of the package *)

SayHello[ name_String ] := Print[ "Hello ", name, "!" ]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

When we are done we simply save the modified file `[Ctrl + s]`.

##### 2.2 Running code

As is the typical development process, once we have written some code, we can test it by *running the project*, for example by entering the context menu for our project directory:

[image]

Even though the `Project Notebook` opens rather quickly, we should patiently wait until the `Console` tab shows `Initialization Complete`:

[image]

As we can see in the `Project Notebook`, our code works just fine:

[image]

While our `Run Session` is still *running*, we can add another function to `MyFirstPaclet.wl`:

```
(* Wolfram Language Package *)

(* Created by the Wolfram Workbench 02.11.2021 *)

BeginPackage["MyFirstPaclet`"]
(* Exported symbols added here with SymbolName::usage *) 

SayHello

SayGoodbye

Begin["`Private`"]
(* Implementation of the package *)

SayHello[ name_String ] := Print[ "Hello ", name, "!" ]

SayGoodbye[ name_String ] := Print[ "Goodbye ", name, "." ]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

Upon saving the modified file `[Ctrl + s]` the console will automatically load the package again:

[image]

And indeed we can immediately test the new code in the project notebook:

[image]

### 3 Deploying the paclet

For what follows I assume that you are going to deploy your paclet to some `paclet server`. Again please refer to [Todd's excellent guide for how to set this up](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/tgayley/Published/PacletDevelopment.nb). Personally, I am using a local directory in my `\Dropbox` directory, which works out nicely.

##### 3.1 Creating a script for deployment

As before, by right clicking on the project directory we add a new `file`, which we call `deployPaclet.wls`:

[image]

We then open `deployPaclet.wls` using the `Text Editor`:

[image]

We then enter the following script, which of course has to be adapted, and save it `[Ctrl + s]`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript

(* deploy the paclet to the local paclet server and update the paclet site files *)
Needs[ "PacletManager`" ]

$localPacletServer = "D:\\Dropbox\\BSLPacletServer" (* the location of the paclet server as needed for CreatPacletArchive[ ] *)

$thisPaclet = "D:\\git-local\\MyFirstPaclet"

CreatePacletArchive[ $thisPaclet, $localPacletServer ]   (* create the .paclet archive *)

PacletManager`BuildPacletSitesFiles[ $localPacletServer ] (* update the paclet site files *)
```

Now, all we have to do is to tell Workbench that `deployPaclet.wls` is a script (it does not know by itself ;-) by entering the context menu with a right click for that file and selecting `open with other...` and `Wolfram Script`:

[image][image]

CLosing the dialog with `Ok` will already run the script and upon inspection of the paclet server directory we find:

[image]

From now on we should be able to deploy the paclet simply by selecting the script file `deployPaclet.wls` and pressing `F3`.

> *Note: If newer versions of a paclet are added to the paclet server, it may be necessary to remove the older versions before updating the index files. I will check this and append the script later on.*

##### 3.2 Using the paclet

If the `PacletSite` is registered, all one needs to do is to install the paclet once into `$UserBasePacletsDirectory` by

```
PacletInstall[ "MyFirstPaclet" ]
```

> Note: There is currently no way to force `PacletInstall` or `PacletInstallSubmit` to install paclets into `$BasePacletsDirectory`, but paclets can be placed there by hand to become visible to all users on the system.

Any notebook that needs the paclet then can use it with `Needs[ ]`:

```
Needs[ "MyFirstPaclet`" ]
```